# How to access the state of a local variable within a method - Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to access the state of a local variable within a method - Vue?

I need to set a value for the dialog so that I can open the popUp.

By porting I want to open the popUp after loading the Then return data.

```
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'PageIndex',
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('example', ['retrievePratica']),
    aulaPratica (tipo, aula) {
      var data = { 'tipo': tipo, 'aula': aula }
      this.retrievePratica(data).then(function () {
        this.$store.state.dialog = true    <------ Here
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Arrow function you can access local data `dialog` by `this.dialog`

```
this.retrievePratica(data)
  .then(() => {
    this.dialog = true
  })
```